# converting query in Query Builder

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

how can I convert this query in query builder.

```
public function ajaxsearch(string $value = null) //for search, from sidebar
{
    return $value ? Teacher::select('id', 'efirst', 'esecond')
        ->whereRaw("UPPER(efirst) LIKE '" . strtoupper($value) . "%'")
        ->limit(7)
        ->get() : [];
}
```

I tried the following but how to convert cases to uppercase in laravel.

```
DB::table('teachers')
    ->select("id", "efirst", "esecond")
    ->limit(7)->get() : [];
```

Comment: you're using query builder in both cases. Dont transform to upper in your database query, do it client side.

Comment: Teacher:: is model, how it is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query :

```
Teacher::select('id', 'efirst', 'esecond')
->whereRaw("UPPER(efirst) LIKE '" . strtoupper($value) . "%'") 
->limit(7)->get();
```

for DB Query :

```
return $value ?
DB::table('teachers')
->select('id', 'efirst', 'esecond')
->whereRaw("UPPER(efirst) LIKE '" . strtoupper($value) . "%'")
->limit(7)
->get():[];
```

Comment: it returned nothing on fronend, here is log; [2019-11-04 09:20:11] local.INFO: array (
  0 => 'select `id`, UPPER(efirst), `esecond` from `teachers` where UPPER(efirst) LIKE \'%A%\' limit 7',
  1 => 
  array (
  ),
  2 => 6.01,

Comment: what you exactly want? columns in upper case? or compare records in upper case?

Comment: i want to get record from database(any case) and show result in upper case.

Comment: in your column efirst it is stored in upper case?

Comment: it has come values in lower case and some upper.

Comment: without where condition, you are getting records?

Comment: your second condition, log: [2019-11-04 09:28:08] local.INFO: array (
  0 => 'select `id`, UPPER(efirst), `esecond` from `teachers` where UPPER(efirst) LIKE UPPER(\'%as%\') limit 7',
  1 => 
  array (
  ),
  2 => 4.0,
)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201821/discussion-between-yasin-patel-and-fayakon).